# d3: acting on a class in response to an event

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm binding data to a bunch of nodes using d3, and I would like to arrange it so that all of the nodes change dynamically when one of them is clicked on (or some other event).  Based on my understanding of d3, I think it should work like this:

```
var nodes = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(someData)
    .enter()
    .append("circle") 
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("class", ".node")
    .style("fill", "blue")
    .on("click", function(d, i) {
        svg.selectAll(".node").style("fill", function(e, j) {
            if(someCondition(i, j))
                return "red";
            else
                return "green";
        });
    });
```

But nothing happens when I click.  Even the simpler code:

```
var nodes = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(someData)
    .enter()
    .append("circle") 
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("class", ".node")
    .style("fill", "blue")
    .on("click", function(d, i) {
        svg.selectAll(".node").style("fill", "red");
    });
```

(which I expect would turn all of the nodes red when one of them is clicked on) does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in the way you are setting the class names for your circles by calling

```
.attr("class", ".node")
```

Doing it this way would set the attribute to `class=".node"` which is certainly not what you want. Moreover, this would not be a valid class name. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/449000/4235784) for an explanation of what characters are allowed to form a class name. To select this class name you *would* have to do a `svg.selectAll("..node")` having two dots in your selector string.

Having said that, change you code to leave out the dot to make it work:

```
.attr("class", "node")
```

Lessons learned:

1. `.attr()` takes the attribute's value literally.
2. When applying a CSS selector, you prefix it with a dot to select a class name.

Comment: Good catch. Further you should also simply say `this` instead of the whole svg.selectAll again within your on click.

Comment: Arg, that was pretty silly, but thanks for the catch.  @BradEvans: wouldn't `this` point only to the node which was clicked?

Comment: Indeed it would! I kind of glossed over the fact that you said "all" -- oops :)

Answer (score -1):

You need specify the "cx" and "cy" properties of a circle, otherwise  you wont see anything.

```
var nodes = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(someData)
    .enter()
    .append("circle") 
    .attr("r", 5)
    //add cx and cy here: 
    .attr("cx", function(d) {return d+10;/*just an example*/})
    .attr("cy", function(d) {return 2*d+10;/*just an example*/})
    .attr("class", "node")
    .style("fill", "blue")
    .on("click", function(d, i) {
        svg.selectAll(".node").style("fill", "red");
    });
```

Comment: That's not correct. Both values will default to `0`, thus drawing a circle around the origin (0,0). I've done this myself to make calculations more easy and translate the circle later on.

Comment: I wrote my own code that work correctly. But I did not even notice it is actually caused by attribute "class". I should have post my code here instead simply copy your code.

Comment: My question was not about how to properly display the nodes in the first place - that is dealt with elsewhere in my project anyway.  I wanted to provide enough context for handling a "click" event to make sense without cluttering the question with irrelevant details.